# RSA decrypt on android lollipop

Tags: ssl, rsa, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, public-key

I have an error with decryption with RSA.
The code works on android 4.4 kit kat, but the same app doesn't work on android 5.0 lollipop.

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulusBytes), new BigInteger(exponentBytes));
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

byte[] decrypted = null;
try {
    // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding");

    // decrypt the text using the public key
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    decrypted = cipher.doFinal(area_fissa_byte);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("error","error");
}
```

The error is: **java.security.SignatureException: error:04067084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data too large for modulus**.

My sdk target is:

`<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />` for android 4.4

Do you know what is the problem?

**EDIT:**
i notice that i have 2 different public keys with different lengths!!!
Android 5: i have 382/383 bit (too small)
Android 4.4: i have 384 bit (ok)

**EDIT2:**
i found that there are differences with android 5.0 for TLS/SSL: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html
But i don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: i read somewhere that SSL initialization was not correct on some android older versions, and that was fixed, so could this be related somehow ?

Comment: @Yazan i don't know. I found that the possible providers are differents (Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();) but the app use always "AndroidOpenSSL". The difference is that for android 4.4 the size of the provider is 127 and for android 5 is 143. Then i have two different key size. Do u know if is there a method to use on android 5 the same keyfactory of android 4.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One bug is how you created the RSAPublicKeySpec:

`new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulusBytes), new BigInteger(exponentBytes));`

In case the first bit of the modulusBytes or exponentBytes is one the number will be interpreted as negative value.

When you work with RSA numbers and BigInteger always use the constructor `BigInteger (int signum, byte[] magnitude)` with `signum=1` for specifying that the number is positive:

`new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes), new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes));`

Comment: thanks a lot! this solve the problem! @Robert But i don't understand why works correct on android kitkat... anyways thanks!

Comment: The chance that the first bit is 1 is 50%. Maybe on KitKat you had an RSA key with first bit of modulus and exponent set to 0? In this case your code would work correct.